# Querying, I want to get 2 like values

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

Here is my query

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%A' AND '%B'
```

It doesn't seem to work, any better query?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. In what way does it not "seem to work"? Do you get an error message? The wrong results? No results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, friend. Perhaps you would like to expand on the question further? Also, please accept answers that have helped you the most, 'tis proper netiquette.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE is an operator that compares two values.

So, your code is asking

```
WHERE
  column like '%A'  /*this returns TRUE or FALSE*/
AND
  '%B'              /*What does this evaluate to?  Its a string! */
```

You need

```
WHERE 
  column like '%A'
AND
  column like '%B'
```

If you are trying to match literal values, you may be able to do the following:

```
WHERE
  column in ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using bad syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%A'
AND column LIKE '%B'
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your attempted query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%A' AND '%B'
```

doesn't make sense.  A column cannot end in both "A" and "B".  Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%A' OR column LIKE '%B';
```